# jQuery refresh div based upon HTML5 data element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

My code is as follows:

```
$('*[data-pickup]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       cache   : false,
       url     : "a.php?pickup",
       data    : {'X': value},
      success: function(data) {
        $("*[data-pick='" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "']").html("HELLO");
        }
      });

    $("*[data-pick='" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "']").html("HELLO 2");
    $("*[data-pick='" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "']").show();
})
```

The AJAX call shows a response when viewed through Firebug, which wasn't being refreshed on the screen, so I changed it to a simple "Hello" response, which still doesn't work.

If I comment out the `.html("HELLO 2")` line, it shows the once hidden div containing the HTML5 data element of `data-pick=1` or `data-pick=2`, etc. (depending on what `attr("data-pickup")` is) which is automatically filled with "Test", so it shows "Test".

If I uncomment the `.html("HELLO 2")` line, the div once shown says "HELLO 2". But, in the case of the commented out `.html("HELLO 2")` line, it should be being updated from "Test" to "Hello" via the AJAX call, but it isn't. If I change the data* to a simple HTML id element and update all the code to `#" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "`, it works the exact same with the data attribute (the AJAX call doesn't update anything).

And when I make a var called "el" and make it equal to `*[data-pick='" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "']`, and then print it to the console it appears as: "*[data-pick='1']" or "*[data-pick='2']", etc. Then if I update all the code from `$("*[data-pick='" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "']").whatever` to `$(el).whatever` (thinking there might be a bug somewhere), it still works the same as before.

So, what have I done wrong? Why won't the div get refreshed via the AJAX call but it will after the AJAX call?

Comment: `this` inside the success function is not the same `this` as elsewhere in the change handler.

Comment: You got it @Roamer-1888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 'this' in the success handler of the ajax function is the ajax function itself not the element that triggered the event handler. What you need to do is store the value of the element `var el = $(this)` then reference that whenever you want to access the element taking advantage of closures.

```
$('*[data-pickup]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var el = $(this);
        console.log(value);
        $.ajax({
           type    : "POST",
           cache   : false,
           url     : "a.php?pickup",
           data    : {'X': value},
          success: function(data) {
            $("*[data-pick='" + el.attr("data-pickup") + "']").html("HELLO");
            }
          });

        $("*[data-pick='" + el.attr("data-pickup") + "']").html("HELLO 2");
        $("*[data-pick='" + el.attr("data-pickup") + "']").show();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('*[data-pickup]').change(function() {
    var self = this;
    var value = $(self).val();
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       cache   : false,
       url     : "a.php?pickup",
       data    : {'X': value},
      success: function(data) {
        $("*[data-pick='" + $(self).attr("data-pickup") + "']").html("HELLO");
        }
      });

    $("*[data-pick='" + $(self).attr("data-pickup") + "']").html("HELLO 2");
    $("*[data-pick='" + $(self).attr("data-pickup") + "']").show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the success function is not the same `this` as elsewhere in the change handler.

Here's a solution :

```
$('*[data-pickup]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var $el = $("*[data-pick='" + $(this).attr("data-pickup") + "']");//here keep a reference to the element(s) of interest.
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "a.php?pickup",
        data: {'X': value},
        success: function(data) {
            $el.html("HELLO");//$el is still available here, from the closure formed by the outer function
        }
    });
    $el.show().html("HELLO 2");
});
```